# How to get underlying type for IEnumerable<T> with Roslyn?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

How can I get an underlying type from `ITypeSymbol` for `IEnumerable<MyType>`? I see `ITypeSymbol.OriginalDefinition` contains link to `IEnumerable<>`, but where can I get `ITypeSymbol` for `MyType`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generic type parameters are a feature of *named* types (as opposed to arrays or pointers).

You need to cast to `INamedTypeSymbol`; you can then look at the [`TypeArguments` property](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/INamedTypeSymbol.cs,73).

Side note: To get the open generic type, use `ConstructedFrom`, not `OriginalDefinition`.